# Theme customizer live preview JS- Trying to bind to an html image url without luck

Tags: theme-development, themes, javascript, html, theme-customizer

I am having a little trouble binding the theme customizer live preview javascript to an HTML `<img src>`- more specifically it is my logo.

Here how the html looks on the page(which is fine and dandy):

```
<a class="footerlogo" href="#top"><img src="<?php echo mytheme_theme_mod( 'footer_logo' ); ?>" /></a> </div>
```

Now my problematic part is the JS - Here are my first two attempts. Both not working.

```
Attempt 1:

    /** Footer logo */
wp.customize( 'mytheme_footer_logo', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        $( '.footerlogo img src' ).html( to );
    } );
} );
```

Attempt 2:

```
/** Footer logo */
wp.customize( 'mytheme_footer_logo', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
    var footer = $( '.footerlogo img' );

     footer.attr( 'href', to );

    } );
} );
```

Can anyone give me assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it seems that I accidentaly used the wrong tag, I used href instead of src. Simple fix:

```
/** Footer logo */
    wp.customize( 'mytheme_footer_logo', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( to ) {
        var footer = $( '.footerlogo img' );

         footer.attr( 'src', to );

        } );
    } );
```